# Bootstrap rem fork?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I realise that Bootstrap would be switching to rem with v4. However, I am using the current version (v3) and I would like to use rem.

Reason? I would like to have buttons on the website that can scale font size for the end user. I believe the best implementation would be if I use rems. If I am wrong, or if there is a better solution, please tell me.

Now, to my question. Is there an existing fork of bootstrap that uses rem or should I just go about creating one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using this gist: https://gist.github.com/jasny/9731895

Answer (score 0):

There is a fork, but it relays on both `em` and `rem` (has fallback to `px`) units, you can find it here - https://github.com/ivayloc/twbs-rem-em